# How do I translate this lambda type from Flow to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I am trying to convert the following code snippet from Flow to TypeScript

```
let headAndLines = headerAndRemainingLines(lines, spaceCountToTab),
      header: string[] = headAndLines.header,
      groups: string[][]= headAndLines.groups,
      arrToObjs: (string[]) => {[string]: any}[] = makeArrayToObjectsFunction(errorInfo, spaceCountToTab, header),
      ....
```

As it stands TS does not like the lambda type of arrToObjs.

> Unexpected token, expected ";" (361:28)
>   359 |       header: string[] = headAndLines.header,
>   360 |       groups: string[][]= headAndLines.groups,
>   361 |       arrToObjs: (string[]) => {[string]: any}[] = makeArrayToObjectsFunction(errorInfo, spaceCountToTab, header),

I've tried surrounding the whole expression with brackets

```
(string[]) => {[string]: any}[])
```

but that doesn't help.

`arrToObjs` is a function that takes an array of strings and returns an array of maps of `{string: any}`. What is the correct way to write this type signature in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your variables:

```
let arrToObjs:(x: string[]) => { [key: string]: any }[];
```

Also, if you return an Array of Maps, you could use the Map type:

```
let arrToObjs:(x: string[]) => Map<string, any>[];
```